# Backend did not recieve the req.formData when making Axios call from frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

After making an Axios call from the front end, the backend did not receive the `req.formData`. It shows the undefined value in MERN application.

Front end code:

```
const handleDp = async(e)=\>{
e.preventDefault()
const file = fileRef.current.files\[0\]
console.log(file)
console.log('11');
let formData = new FormData();
console.log(formData);
formData.append("image",file, file?.name)
await axios.patch('http://localhost:3000/update',{
withCredentials:true,  
formData:formData,
headers: {
'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('token'),
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
},

    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.data.success) {
            console.log("profile updated");
            window.location.reload();
        }

})
}
```

Backend route:

```
router.patch('/update', userMiddleware.upload.single('image'),updateProfile)
```

Backend controller:

```
const updateProfile = async(req,res,next)=\>{
console.log(formData)
const file = req.file
console.log(file)
const data = req.formData
console.log(data);
if(!req.file){
return res.json({error: 'Image is required'})
}
const path = data.path.slice(7)
const filepath = `http://localhost:3000/${path}`
try {
await User.findOneAndUpdate({\_id: req.id}, {$set:{image:filepath}})
console.log("file updated");
res.json({success: true, url:filepath})
} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `formData` have to be the second arguments of axios, not in options object.

For example,

```js
const res = await axios.patch('http://localhost:3000/update', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
});
```

Try similar something to the above one.